# Entity Framework 4 missing features?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, entity-framework, orm

I'm well aware that similair topics have been brought up before
e.g. [Entity Framework 4 vs NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639043/entity-framework-4-vs-nhibernate)

But instead of arguments like:

- NHibernate have been around longer and is more mature
- EF4 is drag n drop and not enterprisy
- EF4 and LinqToSql are ...

I would like to see a more detailed list of features that you consider missing from EF4.

Personally, I think the lack of enum support is the biggest drawback of EF4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ayende did a good work of listing NHibernate advantages over EF here: http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2010/01/05/nhibernate-vs.-entity-framework-4.0.aspx

In a nutshell, NHibernate contains many more ways to improve performance in real world scenarios than EF4 (batching being the most obvious), and more flexibility and extensibility pretty much everywhere.